# How to audit TTY for a specified user in ssh connection?

Tags: ssh

I need a method to audit commands that a specified user type in an ssh connection to my server .

Any Help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user isn't intentionally hiding their activity would something like this work?:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | grep "name_of_command"
```

Or

```
cat /home/user_name_here/.bash_history | grep search_string
```

**Although it might be a better solution to enable PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) TTY auditing:** [pam_tty_audit.8](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_tty_audit.8.html)

Install `auditd` (note: make sure ssh server is installed) and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install auditd && sudo reboot
```

Remove any pam_tty_audit:

```
sed '/pam_tty_audit.so disable=/d' /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Append enable string to the pam.d configuration files:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'session required pam_tty_audit.so enable=*' >> /etc/pam.d/sshd"
```

Start auditd:

```
sudo service auditd status
```

If it is not running:

```
sudo service auditd start
```

And grep tty report for a users UID:

```
sudo aureport --tty | grep $(id -u username_here)
```

Related Reading:

http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html#sec.audit.auditd

https://serverfault.com/questions/336217/how-do-i-log-every-command-executed-by-a-user

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html